# Adobe Bridge/Photoshop - Resize Longest Side and Save For Web, Overwriting Original

Tags: photoshop, adobe-bridge

Here goes!

- I have a folder with dozens of sub folders which contain sub folders
- I would like to resize all images which have any length greater than 800px so the new length becomes 800px
  but the image maintains the same ratio. For example if an image was
  1200x600px it would resize it to 800x400px
- I would then like it to be
  "Saved For Web" or optimised at the very least It would then have to
  overwrite the original since I am using GIFs, JPEGs, JPGs and PNGs

Can this be done all together, can any part be easily done?

I'm on a Mac

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "WordPress would like to resize images"? If WordPress is going to resize them, why do you need to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with ImageMagick. The command is like this, but I would create a backup first:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.gif" -o -iname "*.png" | \
   while read i; do
       echo convert "$i" -resize 800x800 -quality 85% "$i"
   done
```

That says... starting at `dot` (the current directory, you can put a different starting directory here if you like), find all files called "*.JPG" or "*.JPEG" or "*.GIF" or "*.PNG", regardless of upper or lower case, in this directory and all directories below, and pass their names into the while loop. The `convert` command says to resize the image so neither side is over 800px and the aspect ratio is retained, then optimise for Web and overwrite original file.

At the moment, it does nothing, it just shows you the command it would run, so you would need to remove the word `echo` and run it again if you like it. Run some tests on a single image or two first.

You could add `-strip` between `-resize` and `-quality` to remove EXIF data (date/time photo was taken, camera make and lens etc) to make the files smaller too. You can also insert a Copyright string and an IPTC profile to give Copyright, Contact, Source, Object and Credits information - just ask me.

To run the script above, save it in a file called `resizer`, then go into Terminal and do this:

```
chmod +x resizer       # Just do this one time to make the script executable
./resizer              # Run the script
```

To install ImageMagick on a Mac, use `homebrew`. Go to [here](http://brew.sh) and install it with the line of code there. Then do:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

If you don't like ImageMagick, you could maybe use `sips` which is built into OSX but it is nowhere near as flexible. If you wanted to try that, the basic command would be:

```
sips -Z 800 somefile.jpg
```

and it will then resize the image to max 800px on either side. Not sure how to optimise or strip EXIF in `sips`, nor if it works for `PNG` and `GIF` files... Your command would then become:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.gif" -o -iname "*.png" | \
   while read i; do
       echo sips -Z 800 "$i"
   done
```

Comment: So if something was just 100px by 200px it would remain the same?

Comment: Sorry, I got the impression all your images needed reducing. If you have smaller images and you want to prevent upsizing, use `-resize 800x800\>`

Comment: Just saw that on the IM site but thanks :-) seems to be working!